# populate all fields value in the watches window

Tags: delphi, debugging

I need during debugging my Delphi app to get many database fields foreign keys value to use them while debugging a stored procedure behavior. the fields are so many and so I wonder if there is a quicker way to get these values like populating all of them into watches window instead of writing  an expression for every single field I need to watch.

In other words I need to watch all fields values for several tables. I wont need all of them but I can easily pick what I need from a list like this.

currently I am writing watches expression like this:

```
<data module>.<Table Component>.fieldbyname('Field_Name').asinteger
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that purpose I dump fields into trace log e.i. something like this:

```
function IfThen(AValue: Boolean; const ATrue, AFalse: string): string; overload;
begin
  if AValue then
    Result := ATrue
  else
    Result := AFalse;
end;

procedure LogDebugFields(ADat: TDataset; ADirection: string = '');
var
  OwnerName: string;
  Idx: integer;
  Field: TField;
begin
  if not Assigned(ADat) or not (ADat is TDataset) then
    exit;
  if Assigned(ADat.Owner) then
    OwnerName := ADat.Owner.Name + '_'
  else
    OwnerName := '';
  LogDebugStringFmt('Dump of dataset in the state "%s" with "%d" fields',
      [DatasetStateToStr(ADat.State), ADat.Fields.Count],
    OwnerName + ADat.Name, ADirection);
  for Idx := 0 to ADat.Fields.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Field := ADat.Fields[Idx];
    LogDebugContinued(Format('[%2.2d] %-48.48s = %s',
        [Idx, Format('%s (%s%s)', [Field.FieldName, Field.ClassName,
          IfThen(Field.Required, ', NOT NULL)', '')]), Field.AsString]));
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

Not really. There's no way to loop to set up watches, or any way to set watches on multiple database fields at once without some code setup.

In Delphi 2010 and higher, you could write your own [debugger visualizer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Debugger_Visualizers) (see the section on `External-Viewer Visualizers`) to provide a custom view for you, but this would be a pretty extensive task. (There's a sample provided in the `$(BDS)\Source\Visualizers` folder; the external viewer is the `StringListViewer`.)

You can create persistent fields to simplify adding them to the Watch Window (double-click the table component and choose `Add Field...` or `Add All Fields`), and then you can reference them as `datamodule.tablefield.AsInteger`.

Alternately, you can assign the fields to separate local variables, and then just watch them instead):

```
var
  AField: TField;
  AnotherField: TField;
begin
  AField := dm.TableA.FieldByName('FieldA');
  AnotherField := dm.TableA.FieldByName('FieldB');
  ...
end;
```

Then set your watch on `AField.AsInteger` instead, which speeds up setting up the watches a little.

(For non-debugging purposes, declaring local `TField` variables and setting them up before the loop can speed code quite a bit by removing the constant lookup of the field using `FieldByName`.)

The other possibility is to declare and use a local variable that you assign in your loop, and then you can watch that local variable:

```
var
  FieldAValue: Integer;
  FieldA: TField;
begin
  FieldA := dm.TableA.FieldByName('FieldA');
  while not dm.TableA.Eof do
  begin
    FieldAValue := FieldA.AsInteger;
    // Use FieldAValue here instead of the Field.AsInteger, so the
    // compiler doesn't eliminate it. You can add a watch by right-clicking
    // FieldAValue and choosing Debug->Add watch at cursor or Ctrl+F5.
    TableA.Next;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: thanks, that last example should loop through table fields not rows and maybe I can while looping store the field/value pair (as variant) in an ini file later I can open this file and take the values...this would be the most suitable solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly add watches to your project by exiting the IDE and editing the `[Watches]` section in the .DSK file.

Here's an example where I wanted to copy and modify a block of 8 watches (Watch4..Watch11):

**Before**

```
[Watches]
Count=12
Watch0='AEvent.getcustomfieldvaluebyname(splantaskfromdate)',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch1='AEvent.getcustomfieldvaluebyname(splantasktodate)',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch2='aevent.start',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch3='aevent.finish',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch4='FDMPPlan.FEvent1833.start',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch5='FDMPPlan.FEvent1833.finish',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch6='FDMPPlan.FEvent1833.getcustomfieldvaluebyname(''tt_fromdate'')',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch7='FDMPPlan.FEvent1833.getcustomfieldvaluebyname(''tt_todate'')',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch8='FEvent1833.start',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch9='FEvent1833.finish',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch10='FEvent1833.getcustomfieldvaluebyname(''tt_fromdate'')',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch11='FEvent1833.getcustomfieldvaluebyname(''tt_todate'')',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
```

**After**

```
[Watches]
Count=20
Watch0='AEvent.getcustomfieldvaluebyname(splantaskfromdate)',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch1='AEvent.getcustomfieldvaluebyname(splantasktodate)',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch2='aevent.start',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch3='aevent.finish',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch4='FDMPPlan.FEvent1833.start',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch5='FDMPPlan.FEvent1833.finish',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch6='FDMPPlan.FEvent1833.getcustomfieldvaluebyname(''tt_fromdate'')',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch7='FDMPPlan.FEvent1833.getcustomfieldvaluebyname(''tt_todate'')',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch8='FEvent1833.start',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch9='FEvent1833.finish',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch10='FEvent1833.getcustomfieldvaluebyname(''tt_fromdate'')',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch11='FEvent1833.getcustomfieldvaluebyname(''tt_todate'')',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch12='FDMPPlan.FEvent1834.start',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch13='FDMPPlan.FEvent1834.finish',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch14='FDMPPlan.FEvent1834.getcustomfieldvaluebyname(''tt_fromdate'')',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch15='FDMPPlan.FEvent1834.getcustomfieldvaluebyname(''tt_todate'')',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch16='FEvent1834.start',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch17='FEvent1834.finish',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch18='FEvent1834.getcustomfieldvaluebyname(''tt_fromdate'')',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
Watch19='FEvent1834.getcustomfieldvaluebyname(''tt_todate'')',256,0,18,1,1,'Watches',1
```